# Want to send value from my javascript to ruby database(Making a highscore system)

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm using ruby on rails.

In my game which is in JavaScript I have a points integer and I want to post it to my scoring database which is in ruby.

So I can use a controller and the create function to get the value stored into the database but how do I tell the javascript to send the points value to the controller so it can create the entry in the database?

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a request via AJAX. It will allow you to make your request directly via the javascript, and perform actions (like updating the score) when it succeeds via callbacks.

See :
https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp